# Multi Tenant Identity

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to declare identity partitioned by tenant id?

For example I want to have this structure:

```
tenant_id | record_id (auto increment)
---------------------
      1   |   1
      1   |   2
      1   |   3
      1   |   4
      2   |   1
      2   |   2
```

Comment: Why would you want to?  If you're using an `auto_increment`, you're generating a synthetic primary key.  By definition, that means that the key isn't meaningful for anything other than identifying the row.  Why would you care if one tenant sees more than the expected number of gaps in the `record_id` for a single tenant if the `record_id` isn't meaningful?

Comment: @JustinCave for capacity. I know this sound a quite dumb, but 1 mil record with id partitioned by 50 tenants will have highest id around 20k, while not partitioned will have highest id of 1 mil.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no means of partitioning either an `IDENTITY` or `SEQUENCE`. In order to do this you would have to create a table to manage TenantID and RecordID for this table. Then you would need a function that accepts `TenantID` and will return `RecordID`. This means that you need to insert via a stored procedure that can grab that value and then do the INSERT, or *maybe* you can get away with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger, but I am not sure about that given that both `TenantID` and `RecordID` need to be part of the PK.

And if you want this pattern to apply to all tables then you would need to duplicate that custom sequence per each table. This is ok for maybe a few tables, but not more than that.

There are rare occasions when this type of behavior is desirable, but the current reason for requesting this seems a bit suspect (noted in a comment on the question):

> for capacity...1 mil record with id partitioned by 50 tenants will have highest id around 20k, while not partitioned will have highest id of 1 mil.

This is not (or at least *should* not be) a valid concern. The `INT` datatype has a capacity of just under 4.3 billion values. If you start the IDENTITY (i.e. the "seed") at 1, then you get half that range since this is a signed INT and not an unsigned INT. If you want all 4,294,967,296 values, then use `IDENTITY(-2147483648, 1)`.

Comment: Nah I am using bigint FYI. Don't know whether my database will hit the capacity though

Comment: @Fendy How many records per table are you expecting? 4 _billion_ is not enough? Are you aware of the capacity of BIGINT? I have never heard anyone ever being concerned about maxing out BIGINT. I doubt you even need BIGINT in the first place.

Comment: Nah I am using the same design for both header and details (line) tables (surrogate key), planned to use it in multi tenant apps. The header may not get topped capacity, but the lines table can hit around millions easily. Still though, maybe the earth will extinct before my bigint identity hit the top capacity though.

Comment: @Fendy, but even without being able to partition by TenantID, do you really think you will hit 4 billion? Using BIGINT if you aren't going past 4.3 billion is a HUGE waste of space that will decrease performance.

Comment: Can find the code snippet for this solution in another thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/43531674/2933389